# Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 3.0.3 not compatible with UWP

Tags: uwp, azure-mobile-services, nuget-package

I have been trying to connect Xamarin app to Azure mobile app backend and use offline sync. To do that I would like to use SQLiteStore nuget package however I am not able to install it to UWP project (I tried to install it also to bare UWP solution). I know that version 2.0.x works also for UWP, but for 3.0.3 version there is problem somewhere. because i am getting an error during package restore.

`Error Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Napadovac.UWP'.0`

Comment: We have not received anything on this (I'm the person who gets contacted generally).  We also lay out our support channels in our docs, which includes GitHub Issues & Azure Forums, but not email.  Having said that, what's the issue?  You haven't actually said.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you for reply. Problem is as stated, that I am unable to install the package to UWP project. Package restore fails when installing package. Installation of other packages works. This error displays only for SQLiteStore package. This error occurs UWP project within Xamarin solution and also in fresh UWP project with no nuget packages installed (besides the default ones). I have added error mesage when installing nuget package to my original post. Thank you.

Comment: The Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SqliteStore package depends on a number of other packages.  What you have provided is the roll-up last message which says it failed - not the error message that was causing the rollback.  I install this package about a dozen times a week, so I'm guessing something in your setup, but can't really do anything unless I see the actual error.

Comment: Hi Adrian thank you, and looking back on my original message, it was little bit over reacted as I spent a lot of time with finding out what is the problem. So sorry for that. I found out that problem was that by default there was old version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package installed (5.1.) I updated to 5.2.2 and everything works like a charm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more digging into logs and internet I found out that the problem was that I had old version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package installed. Package restore fails if version 5.1. is installed. I updated to version 5.2.2. and it works now.